# Auto-added backslashes in python string formatting, pycharm

Tags: pycharm, string-formatting, python-3.5

I have a wierd behaviour when formatting strings like:

```
"""select username from users, price where pricing_id ='{r}' and price.REQUESTER=users.ID;""".format(r=pr)
```

This gives me :

```
'select username from users, price where pricing_id =\\'ID123\\' and price.REQUESTER=users.ID;'
```

Note the unwanted escapes before each quote mark. Executing the same thing in Python Console gives the right result, but running in (or Evaluate) Pycharm yields auto added backslashes. Have someone encountered something similar? This is py3.5 environment.

**EDIT/**
[image: Picture]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear on where exactly you see the unexpected output when you say "running" because you gave no hint as to how the string might be conveyed to the terminal.  Did you mean the Debugger shows it this way?

In general though, I've always seen PyCharm "do the right thing" by calling the object's `__repr__()` method which by convention is to, if reasonably possible, return a string that could be evaluated to instantiate an identical object.  Thus, the escaped string is valid in that sense.

Python's `str` type is neat in that it prefers to quote values with single-quotes but will resort to double-quotes if the value contains single quotes.  From memory, I don't recall if it ever gets even fancier, say using triple quotes if both are present.

Thus I suspect your "formatted string" is possibly something other than a simple `str` (because it only has single-quotes).  What does `type(FOO)` return where `FOO` is what you've assigned this value to?

Comment: it IS a string, there is no doubt here. However, it doesn't matter, as I tried also with numbers, the result is the same. When I say 'running' I mean run, well you launch a py module. First It generated error 'unexpected caracters' when communicating with database, so I investigated, and I saw that quotes were escaped with backslashes, which is obviously false. I expect my SQL statement to be conveyed to databse as "field='string_value'" not as "field=\\'string_value\\'".

Comment: You did not answer either of my questions.  Programs can, obviously, output info to a terminal in gazillion ways.  `print()` happens to be one way, but I can only guess how your string gets printed.  PyCharm can also output values, but Run itself does not do that unless your program says so.  It's trivial to create object types that emulate a `str` (e.g., a SqlQueryString), but which could behave differently and easily explain what *you* are seeing but that *I* have never seen despite years of using PyCharm daily.

Comment: A picture is  better than 1000 words

Comment: Ah, that helps immensely.  I can reproduce that here with the latest EAP build.  Looks clearly to me to be a bug -- this one in fact: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-19383

Comment: Yep it look's like this one.. I have contacted JetBrains btw, I hope this will be corrected